# How can I easily get a TextReader from an XDocument?

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml, textreader

Given an XDocument instance, how can I easily get a TextReader that represents that instance?

The best I've been able to come up with is something like this (where `xml` is an XDocument instance):

```
var s = new MemoryStream();
var sw = new StreamWriter(s);

xml.Save(sw);

sw.Flush();
s.Position = 0;

TextReader tr = new StreamReader(s);
```

However, this seems a little clunky, so I was wondering if there's an easier way?

---

**Edit**

The above example is equivalent to converting the entire instance to an XML string and then create a TextReader over that string.

I was just wondering whether there's a more stream-like way to do it than reading the entire contents into memory.

Comment: Mark - just occurred to me that I sometimes use a "stream inverter" for cases where some API wants to write to a stream and I need to read from it (i.e. for an ActionResult). This could be adapted to make a "text writer inverter", which would essentially give you true streamed access via `XDocument.Save`, but the downside is that it requires an extra thread to run. Would that help you here?

Comment: @Aaronaught: Thanks, but that's probably too much to make of it. I mainly asked the question out of curiosity. In my current issue, I expect to be parsing a small piece of XML at application startup, so I can definitely live with loading the entire document at once.

Comment: Alrighty, I figured you were trying to send it over a network or something to that effect. I'm curious why you need to do this then, are you using an XML API that can only accept a `TextReader`?

Comment: Yes, I'm implementing an interface that requires me to return a TextReader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  TextReader tr = new StringReader(xml.ToString());
```

Comment: Well, that's definitely better than my original approach, but still not really what I'm looking for (see my edited question). However, +1 one for giving me a one-line alternative :)

Comment: I would perhaps add that calling `TextReader` should be wrapped with `using` since it implements `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but there is a Method `XNode.WriteTo(XmlWriter)`. You could pass it a `XmlTextWriter` to get a textual representation. This probably will take somewhat more code 
to write, but it should be more "stream-like" as you requested :-)

[Edit:] Even easier: There's a method `XNode.CreateReader()` which gives you an `XmlReader`. You'll just have to handle the conversion to text yourself.

Comment: Yes, but that's the rub. Unless I'm missing something, there's no easy conversion from XmlReader to TextReader.